# UIWebView resize to fit Content

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

Here is what I am trying to do,

I have a webView whose frame I am setting as

```
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, Y,screenWidth,1);
```

the y coordinate is calculated based on the height of the other views that are added dynamically which works fine.

the screenWidth is set to 320 or 480 depending on device orientation which also works fine.

Now I want my webView to set it's width as the screenWidth and resize it's height alone to fit the content.

The content could be plainText which I load as

```
        NSData* data=[msgBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];             
        if (data) 
        [self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/plain" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

or HTML which I load as

```
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlMsgBody baseURL:nil];
```

In my WebViewDidFinishLoad method, I am doing this,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {

    CGRect frame = self.webView.frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [self.webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    self.webView.frame = frame;

   CGFloat totalHeight = self.webView.frame.origin.y+self.webView.frame.origin.height+30;

    //the webView is scrolllocked and put on a scrollView so I do this

    [self.theScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, totalHeight)];
}
```

My scrollView on which the webView is put can scroll horizontally. My webView is scrollLocked anyways. So I have to always keep my webView width to be the same as self.view.frame.size.width based on the device orientation and the webView width should change just to fit the content. I accordingly set the scrollView contentSize to allow vertical scrolling.

But the thing is that, the self.webView sizeThatFits method returns weird values and what happens is that when my screenWidth is 320 I get fittingSize.width as 408 and my content goes off screen horizontally and I am not able to show the content properly. Even if I forcibly set the frame of self.webView.frame.size.width = screenWidth, part of the content remains off screen.

How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, size to fit:

> Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its ***subviews***.

This does not give you any information about fitting the webView into it's containing view.
Is it possible that your webView is trying to display something wider than the screenWidth, and since you have it scroll locked, it is showing the whole width?

Comment: It's possible that myWebView is trying to display something larger than the screenwidth. Now the question is, is there a way I could do a textWrap around the screenwidth even if the html/CSS that I am loading in the webView explicitly declares a width greater than webView width?

Comment: I doubt it - the enclosing view will not know anything about what's going on inside the webView.

Comment: no enclosing view. I want the content of the webView to wrap around the width of the webView. Where did I say enclosing view of UIWebView?

Comment: no enclosing view. I want the content of the webView to wrap around the width of the webView. Where did I say enclosing view of UIWebView?

Comment: (Try to stay civil, please).  You implied it - if the html/CSS declares wider than screenwidth, and you want to override that, what is left except something OUTSIDE of the webview?  If you want to do it inside of the html, I'm sure there are ways to do that, but I am no expert on html/css.

Comment: With all due respect, where did I lose civility. I apologize if I had come across as uncivil.

Comment: All I am asking is that, if you don't have control over the CSS/Html content that you are going to populate in your UIWebView, can you tell the webView to retain the html/CSS as is (font size, font formatting etc) and still wrap the content around the width of it.

Comment: Unless you are specifying the html yourself (from inside the iphone app), you will not have control over what the web view does.

Comment: re:civility - I thought your question "Where did I say enclosing view" was angry - if not, I apologize.  (iPhone can be very frustrating.)

Comment: I am looking back at this after a year and I realize that my choice of words was grossly improper for this forum. I am really sorry and I thank you for your support.

Comment: @crypticcoder - communication via text loses a lot of human nuance, so it's very easy to be misunderstood.  Don't worry about it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing the problem of the UIWebView contents not sizing properly when switching from landscape to portrait.

After hunting around for awhile, I found my answer:

"One way I've found to handle this is to reload the content after the resize. When I say "reload," I don't mean the built-in reload function on UIWebView, I mean the actual call to loadHTMLString: baseURL: (or whichever method you use to load your content initially)." [Agent Gold's post on Apple Support forum](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11434305?messageID=11434305#11434305?messageID=11434305)